# Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_res/raw/styles.css at :0

Tags: android, css, permissions, android-resources

I'm trying to install my app on an HTC, android ver 2.2, device via gmail.
The app is signed.
After installaion complete I get a messge about "waiting for debuger" and the app failed.
in the LogCat i get the following messages:

```
09-30 11:29:33.512 I/ActivityManager(161): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.zezebra/.ui.SplashScreenActivity }
09-30 11:29:33.542 I/ActivityManager(161): Start proc com.zezebra for activity com.zezebra/.ui.SplashScreenActivity: pid=2695 uid=10072 gids={3003, 1015}
09-30 11:29:33.602 D/Sensors (161): close_akm, fd=141
09-30 11:29:33.612 D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 296 objects / 11264 bytes in 76ms
09-30 11:29:33.642 W/ActivityThread(2695): Application com.zezebra is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-30 11:29:33.652 I/System.out(2695): Sending WAIT chunk
09-30 11:29:33.722 D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 52 objects / 2288 bytes in 114ms
09-30 11:29:33.792 E/Web Console(1056): Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_res/raw/styles.css at :0
09-30 11:29:33.832 D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 64 bytes in 112ms
09-30 11:29:34.062 D/AK8973  (136): Compass CLOSE 
09-30 11:29:35.732 I/Process (161): Sending signal. PID: 2695 SIG: 9
09-30 11:29:35.732 W/ActivityManager(161):   Force finishing activity com.zezebra/.ui.SplashScreenActivity
09-30 11:29:35.732 I/ActivityManager(161): Killing com.zezebra (pid=2695): user's request
```

How it can be solved?

the manifest is:

> 

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".util.ApplicationContext"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_app"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainTabsActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.zezebra.START_DOWNLOAD" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="www.zezebra.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/mobile/"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            <!-- data android:mimeType="text/*"/ -->
            <data android:mimeType="application/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="model/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="drawing/*"/>
    </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ProfileSetupActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.FileBrowserActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ChooseContactsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".transfer.TransferService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".transfer.BootBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.HistoryActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: could you post the content of AndroidManifest.xml as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is required javascript.......

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javasript"></script>
```